# Foreach Statement Printing Out Incorrect Format

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

First of all I have a array stored in the variable $magazine_issue_pages that if you print the array shows the following.

```
Array ( [0] => http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/1.jpg [1] => http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2.jpg [2] => http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/3.jpg [3] => http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/4.jpg [4] => http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/back.jpg ) 1
```

So the variable definitly is storing the array properly. However when I go to put it in my foreach statement it is incorrect.

Here is my PHP foreach statement

```
foreach ($magazine_issue_pages as $magazine_issue_page) {
    echo '<div style="background:url('.$magazine_issue_page.')"';
}
```

It is printing the following in HTML

```
<div div="" <="" <div="" style="background:url(http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/1.jpg)"></div>
```

Obviously this isn't what I am looking for ha...

Looking more for something like this

```
    <div style='background:url("http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/1.jpg")'></div>
    <div style='background:url("http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2.jpg")'></div>
    <div style='background:url("http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/3.jpg")'></div>
    <div style='background:url("http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/4.jpg")'></div>
    <div style='background:url("http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/back.jpg")'></div>
```

Also on a side note when I am writing my echo in my foreach statement I am slightly overwhelmed. As I need to have the url surrounded in " or ' however I already have both of those used in the echo statement so how am I supposed to surround it?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: escape the quotes using a backslash

Comment: Thats not what its printing actually... its printing: `<div style="background:url(http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/1.jpg)"'` **NOTE the missing `></div>`** Because you are missing the closing bracket and entire closing tag what you say its printing is actuall how its getting parsed.

Comment: http://php.net/printf is your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you do miss a bit of the mark-up in your echo? This should do the trick:

```
foreach ($magazine_issue_pages as $magazine_issue_page) {
    echo '    <div style="background:url(\'' . $magazine_issue_page . '\')"></div>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Another way of doing it, that may make it easier to spot what's missing, is to use a template, like this:

```
$template = '    <div style="background:url(\'{{url}}\')"></div>';
foreach ($magazine_issue_pages as $magazine_issue_page) {
    echo str_replace('{{url}}', $magazine_issue_page, $template) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, and I like your second solution!

Answer (score -1):

Your array should look like this.

```
$magazine_issue_pages = array('http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/1.jpg','http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/2.jpg','http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/3.jpg','http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/4.jpg','http://104.131.209.93/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/back.jpg');
```

And then try this.

```
foreach ($magazine_issue_pages as $magazine_issue_page) {
echo '<div style="background:url(\''.$magazine_issue_page.'\')"></div>';}
```